# Failed to resolve dependencies with pallet-staking in frontier

Tags: consensus, frontier

i am trying to implement n-POS in my frontier and i had to use pallet-staking for that. but when i try to use this dependency in my cargo.TOML file it start giving me error related to frame-benchmarking

**cargo.TOML**

```
[dependencies.sp-version]
branch = 'master'
default-features = false
git = 'https://github.com/paritytech/substrate'
version = '5.0.0'

[dependencies.sp-staking]
git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate"
default-features = false
branch = "master" 

[dependencies.pallet-staking]
git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate"
default-features = false
branch = "master"
```

in std array

```
"pallet-staking/std",
```

**error**

```
error: failed to select a version for `sc-client-db`.
    ... required by package `frame-benchmarking-cli v4.0.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate?branch=master#174735ea)`
    ... which satisfies git dependency `frame-benchmarking-cli` (locked to 4.0.0-dev) of package `frontier-template-node v0.0.0 (/Users/mp-haidera-pyse-403/Desktop/substrate/kories/node)`
versions that meet the requirements `^0.10.0-dev` (locked to 0.10.0-dev) are: 0.10.0-dev

the package `frame-benchmarking-cli` depends on `sc-client-db`, with features: `with-kvdb-rocksdb` but `sc-client-db` does not have these features.


failed to select a version for `sc-client-db` which could resolve this conflict
```

Comment: you need to match the specific commit of all upstream dependencies, usually this is done via tag or branch, check what frontier is using and match - the crate version is not enough. Master changes over time, and thus is not suggested to use in production.

Comment: @DanShields thanks for comment. i added pallet-staking with matching its branch to other branches because frontier was using master for all other dependencies.

Comment: i cloned and then checked out to branch 
polkadot-v0.9.22
then I again added staking dependencies and tried building the project and it was successfully built.
@DanShields please verify if this approach is correct so I can close this question.